# Magento: Update specific Attribute based on SKU

Tags: sql, magento, phpmyadmin

So, this is what I am trying to do.

I have a huge list of EAN numbers that I all need linked to a specific SKU.

```
if SKU = ABCD1234 then EAN = 12345678
if SKU = ABCE1234 then EAN = 12345679
if SKU = ABCF1234 then EAN = 12345670
```

Anyone knows which Magento tables I need to change, and what sort of SQL query I need to do so?

Cheers

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

you can put your sku/ean list in a csv, and use [magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page) to make the update

Comment: foreach ($values as $sku => $ean)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    if($product) {
        
        $product->setEan($ean);
        $product->save();
        $log[$ean] = $product->getSku();
    }

}


Worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I would run the native Magento Import (System->Import/Export). Just create a CSV file with two columns (sku - EAN). Should do the trick for you.

Comment: The problem however is that is errors on non-existing sku's - suppose we receive a supplier file with 100.000 sku's - but we only have 800 of them ....